# How to see if terra node is synced

Tags: terra

I'm running a [terra](https://docs.terra.money/How-to/Run-a-full-Terra-node/Build-Terra-core.html#prerequisites) node using the `terrad start` command.

How can I tell if it's synced?

Answer (score 2):

Run `terrad status`

And look for `catching_up` in the response. If it says `false` it's synced!

Example:

```json
{
  "NodeInfo": {
    "protocol_version": {
      "p2p"  : "8",
      "block": "11",
      "app"  : "0"
    },
    "id"         : "terradocs-id",
    "listen_addr": "tcp://0.0.0.0:26656",
    "network"    : "bombay-12",
    "version"    : "0.34.14",
    "channels"   : "40202122233038606100",
    "moniker"    : "terradocs",
    "other"      : {
      "tx_index"   : "on",
      "rpc_address": "tcp://127.0.0.1:26657"
    }
  },
  "SyncInfo": {
    "latest_block_hash"    : "19ABCBA90BF3E76A0635E6C961AB2CECC7DB2B1F1338057DB334568128E0776E",
    "latest_app_hash"      : "8DFE69CF66FBE7ADCDB5B430A0C679C45B6AEBDDAE23835ABDC4ACBC704F7525",
    "latest_block_height"  : "7333450",
    "latest_block_time"    : "2022-01-08T05:24:57.383258076Z",
    "earliest_block_hash"  : "E88E3641A488EBA3D402FC072879C6399AA2CDC7B6CC5A3061E5A64D9FFD3BDE",
    "earliest_app_hash"    : "E3B0C44298FC1C149AFBF4C8996FB92427AE41E4649B934CA495991B7852B855",
    "earliest_block_height": "5900001",
    "earliest_block_time"  : "2021-09-28T09:00:00Z",
    "catching_up"          : false                         
  },
  "ValidatorInfo": {
    "Address": "29E58C21B6612227C9C9BD9E6D4D99897E032572",
    "PubKey" : {
      "type" : "tendermint/PubKeyEd25519",
      "value": "7cZq+Fp9xU8mZ9xR7q4NpDOX0UicmPC68P/4krCn8Hs="
    },
    "VotingPower": "0"
  }
}
```